# Converting Between Cartesian Coordinates and Spherical Coordinates

Tags: javascript, math

I need to convert between Cartesian and Spherical Coordinates in JavaScript.
I looked briefly on the forums and didn't find exactly what I was looking for.

Right now I have this:

```
this.rho = sqrt((x*x) + (y*y) + (z*z));
this.phi = tan(-1 * (y/x));
this.theta = tan(-1 * ((sqrt((x * x) + (y * y)) / z)));
this.x = this.rho * sin(this.phi) * cos(this.theta);
this.y = this.rho * sin(this.phi) * sin(this.theta);
this.z = this.rho * cos(this.phi);
```

I have used **[Spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)** and **[Cartesian to Spherical coordinates Calculator](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1359533867)** to get my formulas.

However I am not sure that I translated them into code properly.

Comment: so have you tried it out to see if you get the right results?

Comment: The code is not valid as-is, you need Math.* in front of sqrt, tan and sin. Did you run the code to see if the result is correct?

Comment: @K3N I am using the khan academy version of javascript. My program works there are no errors but the math is wrong. Check out my full program here: http://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-for-stack-overflow/5060721748606976

Comment: @PoplopZord ah, ok. I'm adding the tag for khan-acedemy to make it more clear.

Comment: @K3N yup k. New to the forums I guess I should of specified earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes

To get right value of Phi in the full range, you have to use ArcTan2 function:

```
this.phi = atan2(y, x);
```

And for Theta use arccosine function:

```
this.theta = arccos(z / this.rho);
```

Backward transform - you have exchanged Phi and Theta:

```
this.x = this.rho * sin(this.theta) * cos(this.phi);
this.y = this.rho * sin(this.theta) * sin(this.phi);
this.z = this.rho * cos(this.theta);
```

Comment: Many thanks. I had to use acos instead of arccos but I think it is the same thing. Man I feel so happy right now. Thanks!

Comment: Why is there no `Math.` object in your code? Stripped for brevity?

Comment: @Tomáš Zato Because I don't know JavaScript, and don't sure what functions are in it's standard library